# Unsure of how to cast parameters of a function in C to void *

Tags: c, casting, function-pointers

I am writing a generalized hashtable and I have created a typedef:

```
typedef unsigned long(*hashFunction_t)(void*,unsigned long);
```

That represents the hashing function.

I then use this in the function add:

```
int add(HashTable *table, hashFunction_t h, void *data);
```

However, I am getting a warning "initialization from incompatible pointer type" at the line:

```
hashFunction_t hash = JenkinsHash;
```

because JenkinsHash has the parameters:

```
unsigned long JenkinsHash(const char *str, unsigned long mod);
```

So my question is, how do I cast JenkinsHash to have the parameters:

```
(void*,unsigned long)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `hashFunction_t hash = (hasFunction_t)JenkinsHash;` ? You could also try to use empty parenthesis in your typedef : `typedef unsigned long(*hashFunction_t)();`.

Comment: Just declare `JenkinsHash()` as taking a `void *` for its first parameter. You can convert it to a `const char *` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Thanks @Chnossos that does the trick! Seems obvious now that you say it. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I have to ask: What is the purpose of the `unsigned long` param? Please don't say it is the table size and the called-function is responsible for performing the modulo rather than *you* doing it. Just curious. And why is the hash function a *parameter* of the `add()` function? If anything it should be a *property* of the table itself, set during initialization.

Comment: @WhozCraig the unsigned long is for the table size. This is for a school project and we were given JenkinsHash. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "you" doing it. Why is it a bad thing that JenkinsHash (or whatever other hashing function) performs the modulo? As for setting the property of the table, that does make more sense! I am a novice with C, and that seemed like the more logical, "objecty" way to do it, but I wasn't sure if there was a clean way to do it. I now see that there is.

Comment: I hope you understand after thinking about it. The caller-provided *hash function* shouldn't be responsible for returning a value within the domain of the table size; that's the responsibility of the hash table api (it, after all, knows the table size because *it owns the table array*. The function provided should simply take user-data, and be responsible for returning some value in 0...UINT_MAX (or some other native restriction). The hash table api then churns that by performing the modulo (and anything else it needs. And the `add` api should *definitely not* take the hash function as a parm.

Comment: ... continued. That function should be passed as part of the hash table initialization api, and not be mucked with again (though you could provide an api to do *just that*; i.e. change hash functions, which would, of course, trigger a complete rehash of the table nodes, etc). Anyway, hope all that makes sense.

Comment: @WhozCraig I see what you were saying now. Unfortunately, since the provided JenkinsHash took an unsigned long as a parameter, I felt that every hash function should have the same parameters. However in my add function I have the size hardcoded to prevent what you described: unsigned long hashValue = (table->hashFunction)(data,MAX_HASH_SLOT); Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3600375 oh I get why you're doing it. its a class thing. gotta dance with the one you brought and all. no worries. Just something you can casually ask the instructor.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this without invoking undefined behavior is to make a new thunk function with the proper signature that performs the cast for you. The overhead will be minimal and you avoid a very unsafe typecast.

```
unsigned long JenkinsHashThunk(void *str, unsigned long mod)
{
    return JenkinsHash((const char*)str, mod);
}
```

Comment: `void *` is required to have the same representation as `char *`, so this would be at the lesser end of the scale of unsafe typecasts, if there is such a thing :)

Comment: @MattMcNabb that way UB lies. While it's a reasonable assumption, there's no requirement that the type of the parameters has any impact on the representation of the function pointer itself. They can exist in completely different universes if the implementation wants, just as function pointers are assumed by the standard to be incompatible with data pointers unless explicitly allowed by the implementation.